# In Objective-C, how do you initialise a constant from another constant?

Tags: objective-c

```
 NSString* const nits = @"nits";
 NSString* const nuts = nits;  // error: "initializer element is not constant"
```

How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constant String literals such as your `@"nits"` are hardcoded into objective-c binary files. String constants such as `nits` and `nuts` have to be defined as a constant string *literal*, as they are hard-coded as well. The assignment `nuts = nits` does not work because `nits` is not a constant string literal, even though the variable is constant at runtime.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. write the string literal `@"nits"` twice
2. use a `#define`

This might look like this:

```
 #define NitsNutsString @"nits"
 NSString* const nits = NitsNutsString;
 NSString* const nuts = NitsNutsString;
```

Alternatively you can use `#define`s only, but these cannot be exported in a header as cleanly as const strings.

Comment: right, must have had a single event upset in my brain, fixed it ;)
Also feels better now :)

Comment: but now it should be fixed, tx.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know objective-c but I would imagine that by initialising something from a value that is not a literal then you end up with not a constant - regardless of the initial value declaration.